# Mudar cor de item numa listview que contem determinado TEXTO

Tags: android, listview, background-color

Como eu coloca pra quando um item da listview tiver uma informação ela fique com um background com uma cor diferente? No exemplo abaixo ele recebe os dados e os retorna na listview:

```
public List<Cliente> todosOsClientes() {

    List<Cliente> users = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nome.length; i++) {
        users.add(new Cliente(" " + nome[i], " Telefone: " + telefone[i], " Celular: " + celular[i],
                " Renda: R$ " + renda[i], " Limite de Crédito: R$ " + limite[i], " Status: " + status[i],
                " Bandeira: " + bandeira[i], "" + id[i]));
    }
    return users;
}
```

Dentro do for eu tentei:

```
if(status[i].contains("Devendo")){
            lista.setBackgroundColor(0xFFDDEEFF);
        }
```

Porém todo ele fica em azul, eu queria somente os que contem o texto "Devendo"

BaseAdapter:

```
public class AdapterClientesPersonalizado extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<Cliente> cliente;
private final clientes act;

public AdapterCursosPersonalizado(List<Cliente> cliente, clientes act) {
    this.cliente = clientes;
    this.act = act;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cliente.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return cliente.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = act.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_cliente_personalizada, parent, false);

    Cliente cliente = cliente.get(position);

    TextView nome = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_nome);
    TextView telefone = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_telefone);
    TextView celular = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_celular);
    TextView renda = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_renda);
    TextView limite = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_limite);
    TextView status = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_status);
    TextView bandeira = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_bandeira);
    TextView id = (TextView)
            view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_id);

    nome.setText(cliente.getNome());
    telefone.setText(cliente.getTelefone());
    celular.setText(cliente.getCelular());
    renda.setText(cliente.getRenda());
    limite.setText(cliente.getLimite());
    status.setText(cliente.getStatus());
    bandeira.setText(cliente.getBandeira());
    id.setText(cliente.getId());

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: No caso lista seria sua listview? 

O adapter dos dados qual é? Com um custom adapter você consegue fazer isso no item. Mas aconcelharia você a usar uma RecyclerView e fazer o adapter.

Comment: Sim, a lista é a listview, o adapter é o BaseAdapter

Comment: tem como você postar o baseadapter? assim posso ajudar melhor

Comment: Blz, só um momento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só não lembro se o parseColor vai aceitar o jeito que fiz, acredito que sim.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = act.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_cliente_personalizada, parent, false);

Cliente cliente = cliente.get(position);

TextView nome = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_nome);
TextView telefone = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_telefone);
TextView celular = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_celular);
TextView renda = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_renda);
TextView limite = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_limite);
TextView status = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_status);
TextView bandeira = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_bandeira);
TextView id = (TextView)
        view.findViewById(R.id.lista_personalizada_id);

nome.setText(cliente.getNome());
telefone.setText(cliente.getTelefone());
celular.setText(cliente.getCelular());
renda.setText(cliente.getRenda());
limite.setText(cliente.getLimite());
status.setText(cliente.getStatus());
bandeira.setText(cliente.getBandeira());
id.setText(cliente.getId());

if(cliente.getStatus().contains("Devendo")){

  view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFDDEEFF);
}

return view;
}
```

Comment: O app parou de funcionar mano kkkkkk, deu certo não

Comment: Qual erro? estou respondendo pelo celular as vezes passou algo desapercebido

Comment: Consegui aq, nessa parte:view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("0xFFDDEEFF")); deve ficar: view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFDDEEFF));

Comment: Vlw man, mt obrigado.

Comment: Ah, e outra coisa aqui: if(cliente.getStatus.contains("Devendo")){ tem () no getStatus, fica: if(cliente.getStatus().contains("Devendo")){

Comment: Não precisava passar a cor por string, quando usei vinha como parâmetro no json que recebia. Vou editar, que bom que deu certo.